# How can I send requestBody using axios "js"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spring, rest, webpack

I built spring rest api and testing it using postman, it's working. But when I am testing it using JavaScript, I don't know how I can send the requestBody?

//spring rest api

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TmsRestController {
@CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/transaction")
    public List<TransactionBase> getTransaction(@RequestBody TransactionFilters filter) {
        TMSServiceDatabaseImpl tmsService;
        try {
            tmsService = new TMSServiceDatabaseImpl();
            if (filter != null)
                return tmsService.getTransatcions(filter);
            else
                return tmsService.getTransatcions(new TransactionFilters(null, null, null, null, null));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

}

//result in postman
[result in postman][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZIxd.png

---

//javaScript code

```
async function getTransactions() {
  var res;
  try {
    const res = await axios("http://localhost:8080/api/transaction", {
        method: "GET",
      params:{
        "from":"202-02-01",
        "to":"2020-04-17"
      }
    });
    console.log(res);
   } catch (error) {
       alert(error);
   }
}

getTransactions();
```

when run javaScript code :GET http://localhost:8080/api/transaction?from=202-02-01&to=2020-04-17 400 Not Found,I know that using "params" is wrong, but what should I use?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? If yes, upvote the correct one or mark as solved, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the 'data' option instead:

```
try {
    const res = await axios('http://localhost:8080/api/transaction',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                from: "202-02-01",
                to: "2020-04-17"
            }
        }
    );
    console.log('RESPONSE DATA', res.data);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Also, I found a closed issue in Axios Github [#2400](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2400) and the advice was not to use request body when using GET. Btw, that is the workaround if you don't want to use URL parameters. Hope I could help you!

Comment: from official docs: // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
  // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this. That is why I mentioned the Github issue #2400. Tks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
async function getTransactions() {


var res;
  try {
    const res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/transaction',
        params:qs.stringify({
        'from':'202-02-01',
        'to':'2020-04-17'
        })
       });
    console.log(res);
   } catch (error) {
       alert(error);
   }
}

getTransactions();
```

I used [qs library](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) to stringify the request params. You have to deserialize params on back-end.

To deserialize JSON request params, check [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)